# error: cannot access KObject -- class file for kotlin.jvm.internal.KObject not found

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I am trying to integrate Kotlin with an existing java application.  So to test it i create a simple kotlin file and a unit test (in java), that will do something simple.  The purpose of the unit test is to ensure all the configure is correct and in fact i can call kotlin class from java.

This is where i get a little stuck, while executing the build using gradle, i get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [system.err] Sample.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'name()' in type 'JetValueParameter'
[ERROR] [system.err] SampleTest.java:19: error: cannot access KObject
[ERROR] [system.err]         sample.setStatusCode(Sample.Status.OK);
[ERROR] [system.err]                                        ^
[ERROR] [system.err]   class file for kotlin.jvm.internal.KObject not found
[ERROR] [system.err] 1 error
[ERROR] [system.err] 24 warnings
```

I have the kotlin runtime on the classpath, i have also added in kotlin-jdk-annotations just for good measure.  I also have the kotlin plugin configured in gradle.

I'm hitting my head against a brick wall, it'd be a shame as i like kotlin as a replacement for java.  However this issue might scupper my plans.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Update:

Gradle build script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:0.9.976"
}
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '0.9.976'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:0.9.976"
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:0.9.976'
    }
}
```

Java Version: **1.7.x**
Kotlin version: **0.9.976**
Gradle Version: **1.6**

Comment: Post your build.gradle file, please.

Comment: Please share exact versions of Kotlin compiler, runtime and the Kotlin plugin for Gradle you are using. Also, please tell us how exactly you run your test. Any other configuration details would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Updated my question, to include the gradle script, kotlin, java and gradle versions.

Comment: Try adding `compileKotlin {kotlinOptions.annotations = file('annotations')}` to your build.gradle

Comment: @vzamanillo hasn't made any difference, i still get the warnings and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue, as we are using a convoluted gradle setup (it's loading 5 other scripts ;(), the gradle script wasn't adding the kotlin runtime to the path.  Once i fixed that it seems to work.